# .htaccess RewriteRule leads to internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

On my website, I want to access PHP resources without having to supply the `.php` extension, so in `.htaccess`, I say

```
RewriteEngine on

# If applicable, append ‘.php’
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This works. I say `mysite.com/index`, and `index.php` is served.

So far, so good.

But now, when I say `mysite.com/index/a`, I get an internal server error. Why is that? This is only after I have moved to a new web host.

I am not familiar with mod_rewrite; I simply copied the above lines somewhere from Stack Overflow. What might be wrong with them?

Comment: With `mysite.com/index/a` you try to rewrite to `mysite.com/index.php/a` or to `mysite.com/index/a.php` in the directory `index`?

Comment: I would expect and prefer a 404, since `index/a` does not exist, but most Apache installations don't seem to work that way. I'd be fine with a 404 or a served `index.php`, but I don't want an internal server error. To make matters worse, my custom 500 page isn't even displayed. Servers says "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: btw, you can look for details into apache error.log